# List file in sub directory with certain permission

Tags: permissions, ls

So basically I need to list files in sub directory which has all permission for user and group but not other. Basically rwxrwx---

All I got is:

```
 ls -d */*
```

to show the sub directories but now how do I the permission part, I know I need to use "|" but what command do I do?

Thanks!

Comment: The only way I know how to use the find command is with the numbers but I wanna use the letters(eg. rwxrwx---)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `find` command. To get all files and directories with `rwxrwx---` in the branch of current directory use:

```
find . -perm 770
```

If you only need to check for files:

```
find .  -type f -perm 770
```

If you only need to check the immediate subdirectories (in FreeBSD/OSX):

```
find . -depth 2 -perm 770
```

or Linux:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -perm 770
```

Comment: how would you do it for any permission for user and group. Not all permission but any permission

Comment: Did you test the third variant? I don't think `-depth` means what you think it means. You could use `-mindepth 2` instead (and add `-maxdepth 2` if you don't want to descend further - or alternatively change the path to `./*` and just use `-maxdepth 1`)

Comment: @steeldriver Interesting... Of course I tested, but seems it might be a FreeBSD option *`-depth n` True if the depth of the file relative to the starting point of the traversal is n.*

Comment: Ah I didn't know that - thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @shawnedward If you mean a check for effective permissions with those applied via group membership and/or ACLs, then `find` has options for `-executable`, `-readable`, `-writable`. You can check with `sudo -u user_name find . -readable -or -writable -or -executable`.

Comment: @steeldriver I wasn't aware of it either. Thanks for pointing this out.